# vibration/right side shaking when driving past 60 kph, but only when accelerating

Tags: mazda, mazda-3, underbody

What seems to be the problem on my 2005 mazda 3. whenever I try to drive faster than 60kph and and accelerating, there seems to be a vibration that increases when I go faster, but it suddenly stops when I stop pressing the accelerator. What seems to be the problem? A CV Joint?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "increases"? The severity of the vibration increases, or the vibration rhythmically goes up with speed? If you bring it up to 70kph and stop accelerating but maintain speed, does it stop vibrating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this is CV joint/axle related as if that was the case you'd feel the vibration regardless of the throttle position. If the problem only occurs during acceleration I'd lean more towards the possibility of a failing/worn engine mount or pitch stopper/dog bone.

Comment: Yes it seems that the engine mounts were actually the culprit. Already fixed and working just fine.

Comment: Actually, I had this exact problem and after replacing my axle the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

Check the engine mount or the main pulley (balancing shaft harmonic balancer).